# Alfresco installation on windows server 2012 with SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, alfresco, ibatis

I'm new here.
I want to install an old version of alfresco community 4.0.d on sql server 2012. I saw on topics that it worked. For some days I have errors that are displayed. I will need your help. please.

My configurations:

```
db.driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
db.username=alfresco
db.password=alfresco
db.name=alfresco
db.host=localhost
db.port=1433
db.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/alfresco
db.txn.isolation=4096
```

My log error:

```
2018-04-05 13:54:45,325  ERROR [web.context.ContextLoader] [Thread-1] Context initialization failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'encryptionKeysRegistry' defined in class path resource [alfresco/encryption-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'attributeService' while setting bean property 'attributeService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'attributeService' defined in class path resource [alfresco/attributes-service-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'propertyValueDAO' while setting bean property 'propertyValueDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'propertyValueDAO' defined in class path resource [alfresco/dao/dao-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'propertyValueSqlSessionTemplate' while setting bean property 'sqlSessionTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'propertyValueSqlSessionTemplate' defined in class path resource [alfresco/ibatis/ibatis-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'repoSqlSessionFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repoSqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [alfresco/ibatis/ibatis-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse config resource: class path resource [alfresco/ibatis/alfresco-SqlMapConfig.xml]; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Failed to get resource: alfresco/ibatis/#resource.dialect#/audit-insert-SqlMap.xml
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:905)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:740)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:500)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Need your help please

Comment: Excuse me. Hello...

Answer (score 2):

I think the SQL Server 2012 is not compatible with alfresco community version.

We can configure SQL Server for "`Alfresco Enterprise` Version" not for "`Alfresco Community Edition` Version".

SQL server is not supported by Alfresco Community Edition.

So, Alfresco Community Edition will not work with SQLServer.